# Can I link class field to multiple classes in orientdb?

Tags: javascript, typescript, orientdb

Consider there is one field 'player' of any orientdb class, can we link this field with multiple classes such as Teams, Groups, Users etc. I know we can link this field with single class and in that field we can store @rid of record in link class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely, you do it in a schemaless way:

```
INSERT INTO AClass SET aLinkProperty = #9:0
```

But you can also define a schema for the proplerty, without defining the class for the link:

```
CREATE PROPERTY AClass.aLinkProperty LINK
```